# AngularJS including partial template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm using the angularjs ui router with this code

```
.state('posts', {
                url: '/posts/{id}',
                templateUrl: '/javascripts/templates/posts.ejs',
                controller: 'PostsCtrl',
                resolve: {
                  post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function($stateParams, posts) {
                    console.log("post: ", posts.get($stateParams.id));
                    return posts.get($stateParams.id);
                  }]
                }
            })
```

And this is the script inclusion

```
<body ng-app="...">
<div>
<ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
....
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="/javascripts/templates/posts.ejs" src="/javascripts/templates/posts.ejs">
```

This is the ejs(html) file itself

```
<div class="page-header">
        ....
  </div>
```

However, I cannot get the source which holds the ejs file to load. When I go to the correct url /posts/{id}, no ejs (html) loads and there are no console errors. Any idea how to load my ejs file from /javascripts/templates/posts.ejs instead of writing it inline? Too much inline code :(

Thanks!

Comment: Can you navigate to /javascripts/templates/posts.ejs manually in the browser?

Comment: Don't you need a `<div ng-view></div>` tag in your index where it'll load your `templateUrl`? You can also use `ng-include` by itself.

Comment: Yes I can navitage directly in the browser, what is the <div ng-view> in the index?